# Why am I getting a cycle error when setting a S3 bucket policy with a template file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have the following, when I try and run a "terraform plan" it is failing.

```
data "template_file" "s3_bucket_policy" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/s3_bucket_policy.json")}"

  vars = {
    bucket_arn            = aws_s3_bucket.app_bucket.arn
    vpc_endpoint_id       = var.vpc_endpoint_id
    vpc_tools_endpoint_id = var.vpc_tools_endpoint_id
  }
}
```

The output says `Error: Cycle: data.template_file.s3_bucket_policy, aws_s3_bucket.app_bucket` - `aws_s3_bucket.app_bucket.arn` was created earlier successfully.

I'd be happy with suggestions on how to troubleshoot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if your `aws_s3_bucket.app_bucket` resource refers to `data.template_file.s3_bucket_policy`.

Sharing your entire `.tf` file will be helpful.